# SwiftUI Помогите определить причину ошибки Index out of range

Tags: coredata, swiftui

Пожалуйста, разъясните начинающему в чем ошибка.
Пытаюсь из Core Data получить данные и вывести их как текстовые поля. В onAppear делаю заполнение массива с типом MyMessage. Для контроля вывожу на печать через print. Вижу, что массив заполнен корректными данными. Но при попытке вывести элементы массива в текстовые поля получаю ошибку:

Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444

Вот код:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct MyMessage: Codable, Hashable {
    let msgHeader: String
    let msgBody: String
    let msgFooter: String
}

struct MyMessageView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    @State private var showMsg = [MyMessage]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.showMsg[0].msgHeader)
                .padding(.bottom, 10)

            Text(self.showMsg[0].msgBody)
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
            
            Text(self.showMsg[0].msgFooter)
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Message"), displayMode: .inline)
        .onAppear(){
            // from Core Data
            let requestM = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Messages")
            let sortDescriptorM = NSSortDescriptor(key: "msgId", ascending: true)
            requestM.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "msgId == %@", NSNumber(integerLiteral: 1))
            requestM.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptorM]
            do {
                let resultM = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(requestM) as NSArray
                
                self.showMsg.append(MyMessage(
            msgHeader: (resultM[0] as AnyObject).msgHeader,
            msgBody: (resultM[0] as AnyObject).msgBody,
            msgFooter: (resultM[0] as AnyObject).msgFooter
                ))

                Print(self.showMsg[0])

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        } //onAppear
    } //body
}
```

Если я отказываюсь от использования массива и ввожу отдельные переменные для каждого элемента, то все работает отлично. Но у меня есть чувство, что так делать не совсем правильно.

Это код второго варианта

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct MyMessageView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    @State var msgHeader = ""
    @State var msgBody = ""
    @State var msgFooter = ""


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.msgHeader)
                .padding(.bottom, 10)

            Text(self.msgBody)
                .padding(.bottom, 10)

            Text(self.msgFooter)

        }
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Message"), displayMode: .inline)
        .onAppear(){
            // from Core Data
            let requestM = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Messages")
            let sortDescriptorM = NSSortDescriptor(key: "msgId", ascending: true)
            requestM.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "msgId == %@", NSNumber(integerLiteral: 1))
            requestM.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptorM]
            do {
                let resultM = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(requestM) as NSArray
                
                msgHeader = (resultM[0] as AnyObject).msgHeader
                msgBody = (resultM[0] as AnyObject).msgBody
                msgFooter = (resultM[0] as AnyObject).msgFooter
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        } //onAppear
    } //body
}
```

Как решить проблему Index out of range для первого варианта?

**UPD**
Как вариант решения на уровне костыля, это делать перед выводом проверку на пустоту массива через if isEmpty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь проблема в том, что `onAppear` срабатывает позже, чем впервые выполняется код внутри `VStack` (можете проверить, установив там точку останова), когда массив `showMsg` еще пустой. Исправить можно например так (упрощенный вариант без класса для модели Core Data)

```
struct MyMessageView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @State private var showMsg = [MyMessage]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.showMsg.first?.msgHeader ?? "")
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
            
            Text(self.showMsg.first?.msgBody ?? "")
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
            
            Text(self.showMsg.first?.msgFooter ?? "")
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Message"), displayMode: .inline)
        .onAppear(){
            // from Core Data
            let requestM = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Messages")
            let sortDescriptorM = NSSortDescriptor(key: "msgId", ascending: true)
            requestM.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "msgId == %@", NSNumber(integerLiteral: 1))
            requestM.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptorM]
            do {
                let resultM = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(requestM) as! [NSManagedObject]
                
                self.showMsg.append(MyMessage(
                    msgHeader: resultM.first?.value(forKey: "msgHeader") as! String,
                    msgBody: resultM.first?.value(forKey: "msgBody") as! String,
                    msgFooter: resultM.first?.value(forKey: "msgFooter") as! String
                ))
                
                print(self.showMsg[0])
                
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            
        } //onAppear
    } //body
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо за разъяснения, все заработало! Вы упомянули, что это можно сделать с помощью классов. А как, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Хотел проплюсовать, но увы, не хватает авторитета. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @AlexeyPolunin галку поставьте возле ответа, если он вас устроил

Comment: @AlexeyPolunin см например про классы Наследование и кодогенерация
https://m.habr.com/ru/post/436510/